# OpenShift CreateContainerError - Error: mkdir /../../ not a directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, openshift

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application from GitHub to Openshift and getting error on creating pod.
Using oc new-app [GIT REPOSITORY] --as-deployment-config
Here is Dockerfile - multistage build

```
# Build stage
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim AS build
COPY . /cgi
ENV HOME /cgi
WORKDIR /cgi
# Set permissions to the /cgi folder (for OpenShift)
RUN chgrp -R 0 /cgi && chmod -R g+rwX /cgi
RUN mvn install
# Package stage
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /cgi
ENV HOME /cgi
COPY --from=build /cgi/target/dentistapp-1.0.jar /cgi
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar dentistapp-1.0.jar
```

Build stage says - Push successfull, however deploy gives error -

Warning  Failed          83s                kubelet            Error: mkdir /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/b0b9cfcc7eed8f09933b82795f7f18c0aacee0f611ee60f0e9bf56c378597b70/merged/cgi: not a directory

When building this image locally with docker build command and run it everything works fine.

Could you please help to figure out where is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Changing destination path to . in the line below fixed the problem, probably because WORKDIR was already /cgi
COPY --from=build /cgi/target/dentistapp-1.0.jar .